# Unable to create image using mvn spring-boot:build-image command in docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am trying to use the following command in spring-boot using maven spring-boot plugin for generating docker image.

1. The docker daemon is running on Ubuntu on WSL2 .
2. STS terminal window was used to trigger the mvn spring-boot:build-image command.

I was expecting that an image be create in docker.
Instead I am getting the following error with maven build failed.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.3:build-image (default-cli) on project HelloWorld: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframewor
> k.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.3:build-image failed: Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with error "\.\pipe\docker_engine"; ensure the Docker daemon is running
> and accessible -> [Help 1]

The spring boot helloworld app is a simple application created using spring-starte-project in sts.

Any suggestions/solutions to overcome the issue?

Comment: ...well, is the docker daemon running and is accessible from where you are running the app?

Comment: Do you run the terminal from which you start the command in windows or in wsl2?